# Xamarin Android: how to display/Bind List in ListView?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, listview, xamarin.android

I tried a few ways to bind  List elements to ListView but it did not work out. I always get the error "can not convert List

```
List<string> numbersListString= new List<string> {
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three",
        "Four",
        "Five",
        "Six",
    };

listView numbersListView = root.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.numbers);


var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Context,
               Android.Resource.Layout.ActivityListItem, numbersListString);

adapter.AddAll(Android.Resource.Layout.ActivityListItem);
            numbersListView.Adapter = adapter;
```

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. People won't write your code for you here. They only help you solve problems with the code you already have.

Comment: I didn't ask to write the entire code or even a code. I asked for guidance without writing any code

Comment: It will be cool if you could post the code giving that error.

Comment: I just added the code.

Comment: You could check  my answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:** It seems that you used the value of params **textViewResourceId** as `ActivityListItem` in **ArrayAdapter** . However , it requires the source ID to be a **TextView** , not a string .

**Solution:** You can use `SimpleExpandableListItem1` instead of it.

```
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(context, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem1, numbersListString);
```

For more details about `List Item Layouts` you can check https://robgibbens.com/androids-built-in-list-item-layouts/